# Angular 4+ : Why isn't ng-if working in app.componet.html?

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, angularjs-ng-if

I am currently trying to use an ng-if directive in my app.component.html file:

```
<p>This should appear.</p>

<p ng-if="0==1">This shouldn't, but it does.</p>
```

My app.component.ts file looks like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

I have tried numerous different values instead of `0==1` and it still doesn't work, including using the value of a passed-in variable.  It is compiling and displaying without errors, but is not removing the second `p`.

I have also tried `*ng-if`.  When I do that, I get an error:

```
Template parse errors:

Can't bind to 'ng-if' since it isn't a known property of 'p'. ("<p>This should appear.</p>

<p [ERROR ->]*ng-if="0==1">This shouldn't, but it does.</p>

"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@2:3
Property binding ng-if not used by any directive on an embedded template. 
Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("<p>This should appear.</p>
```

Comment: In Angular 2+, it's `*ngIf`

Comment: Ok, that's good to know, since there is a lot of different documentation floating around.  I should have mentioned that among the many things I have already tried, `*ng-if` is one of them.

Comment: Alright, so it wasn't just the asterisk that was the issue; I also needed to remove the hyphen and capitalize the 'i'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular structural directives are prefixed with an asterisk (*) and the directive is written without the dash. Check the official documentation for details:

To fix you code write `*ngIf` instead of `ng-if`.

https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#asterisk

Quick glimpse why from the official docs:

> The asterisk is "syntactic sugar" for something a bit more complicated. Internally, Angular translates the *ngIf attribute into a  element, wrapped around the host element.

Answer (score 0):

In Appcomponent:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
isShowing = true;
}
```

In your markup:

```
<p *ngIf="isShowing">This shouldn't, but it does.</p>
```